# Item of a list contains values of another list Python

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for something like this. I need to compare item 0 from my list of list and if item of list b contains it, change item of b to item of a.

```
a = [['12','0.4'],['13','0.4'],['14','0.4']]
b = ['122','133', '144']

for item in a:
    for item[0] in item:
        if item in b:
            replace b for item



output:

a = [['122','0.4'],['133','0.4'],['144','0.4']]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
a = [['12','0.4'],['13','0.4'],['14','0.4']]
b = ['122','133', '144']
for list_a in a:
    for item_b in b:
        if list_a[0] in item_b :
            list_a[0] = item_b
            break
print(a)
>>> [['122', '0.4'], ['133', '0.4'], ['144', '0.4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in a:
  for i in range(len(b)):
    if item[0] in b[i]:
        item[0] = b[i]
        break
Output: a = [['122', '0.4'], ['133', '0.4'], ['144', '0.4']].
```

You should read the "for" loop in python, this is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

A list-comprehension utilizing `next()` with a *fall-back* value would also do the trick:

```
a = [[next((r for r in b if x in r), x), y] for x, y in a]
```

That prints the desired:

```
[['122', '0.4'], ['133', '0.4'], ['144', '0.4']]
```

Given that `next()` *short-circuits*, this approach is entirely equivillent to the one with the 2 `for` loops and the `break` but much shorter and imho just as readable..

Comment: Mind elaborating on that -1?